# Measuring algorithm runtime accurately with MATLAB

Tags: algorithm, matlab, time, execution

I am trying to measure the running time of the code below.

```
function out=load_database()

    persistent loaded;
    persistent w;
    if(isempty(loaded))

    A=zeros(10304,400);
    for i=1:40
        cd(strcat('s',num2str(i)));
        for j=1:8
            a=imread(strcat(num2str(j),'.pgm'));
            A(:,(i-1)*8+j)=reshape(a,size(a,1)*size(a,2),1); 
        end 
        cd ..
     end
     w=A;
     end

     loaded=1;
     out=w;
end
```

I tried using `tic` and `toc` but it does not work properly because the measured 
time is like 2-3 seconds when in reality it takes almost 20 seconds until everything is done.

This code is for ORL database: http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/dtg/attarchive/facedatabase.html
and it loads only 8 out of 10 images. 8 for training, the other 2 for testing. Not the best way, but is ok for me.

Comment: I tried those too, before asking here. Still, only ~2-3 seconds measured. Then the code does something else, that i don't know how to measure.

Comment: So the Profiler Time is 16 seconds. And this line a=imread(strcat(num2str(j),'.pgm'));  has 320 calls and 1.72 time.

Comment: @JohnDow please add the code that you used to measure time with `tic` and `toc`